# Blueimp Image Gallery: Borderless mode as default?

Tags: image, gallery, blueimp

I'm trying to setup a Gallery similiar to the [demo one](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/), but with only one option, the fullscreen mode. The borderless mode should be default for everyone and not be able to changed.
The documentation gives this hint:

```
Bootstrap Image Gallery provides the additional useBootstrapModal option, which enables the original borderless layout as seen in the demo. The easiest way to enable this option is to adjust the lightbox container and set the data-use-bootstrap-modal attribute to false
```

However, if I do that, it wont look as pretty (no autoplay, no arrows, no small previews at the bottom.
Im trying to find a workaround for serveral days now, but wasnt able to do that.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the div to this worked for me

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-use-bootstrap-modal="false">
```